# Scala: how to apply a function over a function-variable?

Tags: scala

I have a class which gets a function as a variable:

```
class Element[T](func: Seq[T] => Option[Double])
```

I'd like to have another constructor: `def this(func: Seq[T] => Double)`. How do I create a `Seq[T] => Option[Double]` out of `Seq[T] => Double` without knowing what the function is?

Comment: Ok, but is there still a way to do the conversion I'm looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy to make `Seq[T] => Option[Double]` out of `Seq[T] => Double`.
Just do `func andThen Option.apply`.

The problem is that you can't have `def this(f: Seq[T] => Double)` when your main constructor is `Seq[T] => Option[Double]`. These are the same signatures. A neat trick to work around that is using `dummyImplicit`:

```
 class Foo[T](f: Seq[T] => Option[Double]) {
   def this(f: Seq[T] => Double)(implicit dummy: DummyImplicit) = this(
      f andThen Option.apply
   )
 }
```

This makes the calling sequence of the second constructor formally different, so that you can still have it even though the first parameter type is the same as in the first one.